# Extract data from XML with file_get_contents to php

Tags: php, xml

I'm sending a request to an API which sends a response in XML format.

The response looks like this:

```
<ns2:HotelInformationResponse hotelId="263933">
<customerSessionId>0ABAAA85-112B-0914-9322-CA866D907EF8</customerSessionId>
<HotelSummary order="0">
<hotelId>263933</hotelId>
<name>Nova Platinum Hotel</name>
<address1>562 Moo 10 Pratamnak Road, Nongprue</address1>
<address2>Banglamung</address2>
<city>Pattaya</city>
<postalCode>20260</postalCode>
<countryCode>TH</countryCode>
```

How can I get this data so I can print individual values like hotelId or name ?

I have tried like this:

```
$Geosearch = 'APICALLURLHERE';
$fileContents = file_get_contents($Geosearch);
$string_data = $fileContents;
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string_data);
$hotel_id = (string) $xml->hotelId;
$hotel_name = (string) $xml->name;
echo $hotel_id.' '.$hotel_name;
```

Also I have tried this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("APICALLURLHERE");
echo $xml->hotelId;
echo $xml->name;
```

Comment: by the way its `hotelId` not `HotelId`. so whats the problem

Comment: That was a typo but doesn't make any difference anyway, corrected.

Comment: is this the complete response?

Comment: fairly straightforward on this end, if i would just straight up copy that sample xml that would also be my answer like the one you have. you have to post the complete one. most likely there still something to it that is not posted here

Comment: Question updated with the complete response.

Answer (score 0):

**Acces to remote files**

The fopen family of functions, including file_get_contents and simplexml_load_file) by default do no allow access to remote files. This is a very good thing and should stay that way.

If you want to enable remote files, you have to change your PHP configuration.

http://php.net/manual/en/features.remote-files.php

```
allow_url_fopen = 1
```

---

**Errors in a XML file**

If your file loading is working but you STILL do not get your XML working, you may have a broken XML file. You can debug these issues with this snippet:

```
$doc = simplexml_load_string($xmlstr);
if (!$doc) {
    $errors = libxml_get_errors();

    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        echo display_xml_error($error, $xml);
    }
    libxml_clear_errors();
}
```

http://php.net/manual/de/function.libxml-get-errors.php

Comment: If I just `$url = "APICALLURL"; echo file_get_contents($url);` the whole response gets printed, so this can't be the problem?

Comment: You are right, but then the only other problem that come to mind is a broken XML file. What's in your error log and what is the response from simplexml_load_something() ?

Comment: Answer updated for potential xml errors